# y label is stuck on the right side of the graph

Tags: pgfplots

I try to get y label on the right side of the figure, but the label is still stuck on the left side. Below is an example borrowed from another user here. It must be something very simple, but just I couldn't figure what it is. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ylabel=Left label]
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[ticks=none,ytick pos=right,ylabel=Right label]
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome at Tex.sx! This could be caused by backwards compatibility mode. Does it help to add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}` into the preamble?

Comment: Does section 4.9.10 of the recent documentation of `pgfplots` help?

Comment: I add \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9} in the preamble it gives me an error message.

Answer (score 4):

If I add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}` in the preamble, I get the `Right label` on the right side. The best option is to update your `pgfplots` to the latest version and add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}`.

According to Christian Feuersänger (the author of `pgfplots`) putting `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}` would work.

However, as the labels are normal `tikz nodes`, you can put one by yourself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ylabel=Left label]
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[ticks=none,ytick pos=right]
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)};
\end{axis}
%% We put the node as label
\node[rotate=90,anchor=center] at ([xshift=0.3cm]current bounding box.east) {Right label};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is, this thing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9} doesn't work either.

Comment: @user46027 It works for me with latest `pgfplots`. My code for manually putting the label is provided as plan B :) Does it work for you?

Comment: I suppose `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}` should suffice.

Comment: It works just fine. Thanks a lot! However, it is still not a "right" way, since the option would be "ylabel=Right label", but I still have a problem with that.

Comment: @HarishKumar thanks - but note that it was more a comment to the OP's comment that 1.9 would not work on his machine (perhaps he doesn't have 1.9). By no means was it meant as criticism to your answer (sorry for being imprecise).

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Not at all. Please do comment. I am glad to hear from  you :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure. Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ylabel=Left label]
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[yticklabel pos=right,ylabel=Right label, ylabel near ticks]
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No it doesn't work. It give an error message by doing pdflatex.

Comment: @user46027. It works for me! Could you give us more information about this error?

Comment: It says ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/ylabel near ticks' and I 
am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. I have Ubuntu Linux and according to the Ubuntu Software Center I have pdf version pgf 2.10-1.

Comment: @user46027  And which pgfplots version do you use? I'm using 1.9

Comment: 1.2.2. It seems to be quite old, isn't it?

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out where my mistake was lying! After upgrading my pgfplots everything works just fine.